# unordered_map max_size

Tags: c++

I am using `std::unordered_map` and was trying to get the memory consumption so I did the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    unordered_map<int, int> map;
    map[21] = 12;

    cout << map.size() << endl << map.max_size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

to which the result is:

```
1
1152921504606846975
```

the first one is correct, what the heck is the second one?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
map.max_size()
```

Returns the maximum potential size the container can reach due to system or library implementation limitations.

---

```
map.size()
```

Returns the number of elements in the container.

Comment: Oh, i see. So this is not some buffer size? So then in this case is the memory consumption equal to `map.size() * 2 * sizeof(int)` or is there some "hidden" memory usage?

Comment: @GradGuy: There *might* be some overhead due to memory needed by the container itself. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720507/how-can-i-estimate-memory-usage-of-stlmap)

Answer (score 2):

Check cppreference: [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/max_size/)

> **map::max_size**
>
> Return maximum size
>
> Returns the maximum number of elements that the map container object
>   can hold.
>
> This is the maximum potential size the container can reach due to
>   system or library implementation limitations.

Answer (score 1):

max_size()

Returns the maximum number of elements that the map container object can hold.

Answer (score 1):

It's an upper bound on the maximum number of elements the container could potentially hold.